# Langchain(HuggingFaceModel) - argument needs to be of type (SquadExample, dict)

Tags: langchain, large-language-model

I am trying to build an RAG Question Answering Model using Langchain and HuggingFacePipeline.

```py
model_name = "Intel/dynamic_tinybert"

tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained(model_name, cache_dir="../assets")

question_answerer = pipeline(
    "question-answering",
    model=model_name,
    tokenizer=tokenizer
)

llm = HuggingFacePipeline(
    pipeline=question_answerer
)
```

While trying to get any query result as:

```py
llm("What is the mass of the sun?")

The error is:

argument needs to be of type (SquadExample, dict)
```

Any solution or insights? Am I doing anything wrong?

The `llm` model should return me the answer. I am trying a RetreivalQA Chain to chain my prompts and get the output from vector store retreiver as:

```py
qa = RetrievalQA.from_chain_type(llm=llm, chain_type="stuff", retriever=retriever, return_source_documents=True, chain_type_kwargs={"prompt": prompt})
```

Answer (score 1):

Upon looking at the `HuggingFacePipeline` source code, I found it only supports below pipelines:
`` text-generation`, text2text-generation and summarization ``

I went with `text2text-generation` for my use case as it supports generating answers from context and question.

Hope it helps if someone encounters similar issue.

Edit: The model `Bert` no longer works, I had to use the model in category `text2text-generation`

Comment: When I tried `text2text-generatio` I get the following error:
`
'transformers.models.auto.modeling_tf_auto.TFAutoModelForSeq2SeqLM'>). See t
ValueError: Unrecognized configuration class <class 'transformers.models.bert.configuration_bert.BertConfig'> for this kind of AutoModel: TFAutoModelForSeq2SeqLM.
Model type should be one of BartConfig, BlenderbotConfig, BlenderbotSmallConfig, EncoderDecoderConfig, LEDConfig, MarianConfig, MBartConfig, MT5Config, PegasusConfig, T5Config.

`

Comment: Do you have any sample code I could refer to?

Comment: @Wolfy Sorry for my incomplete answer. In order to use `text2text-generation`, you have to use models in that category only and Bert is only for `question-answering`.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the issue is that inter/dynamic_tinybert was fine-tuned for abstractive QA. It means that it will only support `task="question-answering".

Please see the docs below.

Question answering

Question answering is another token-level task that returns an answer to a question, sometimes with context (open-domain) and other times without context (closed-domain). This task happens whenever we ask a virtual assistant something like whether a restaurant is open. It can also provide customer or technical support and help search engines retrieve the relevant information you’re asking for.

There are two common types of question answering:

extractive: given a question and some context, the answer is a span of text from the context the model must extract.

abstractive: given a question and some context, the answer is generated from the context; this approach is handled by the Text2TextGenerationPipeline instead of the QuestionAnsweringPipeline shown below

```
from transformers import pipeline

question_answerer = pipeline(task="question-answering")
preds = question_answerer(
    question="What is the name of the repository?",
    context="The name of the repository is huggingface/transformers",
)
print(
    f"score: {round(preds['score'], 4)}, start: {preds['start']}, end: {preds['end']}, answer: {preds['answer']}"
)
score: 0.9327, start: 30, end: 54, answer: huggingface/transformers
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response. But, my implementation is fully based on HuggingFacePipeline. So I wanted a solution around that only.

Answer (score 0):

When using `"question-answering" Pipeline` the prompt should be a `SquadExample`instead of a `String`.
Use [create_sample](https://huggingface.co/docs/transformers/v4.37.2/en/main_classes/pipelines#transformers.QuestionAnsweringPipeline.create_sample) to create a `SquadExample`.

Comment: Please provide a sufficient solution to the question.

Answer (score 0):

HuggingFacePipeline does only support `text-generation`, `text2text-generation` and `summarization`. But even with `text2text-generation` I was getting this error. I think there could be a bug in `langchain >= 0.1.8`. Downgrading to `langchain==0.1.7` solved the problem for now.

Comment: Hi, downgrading is still not working for me.

Comment: sorry to hear. I have used langchain==0.1.7. 

```model_name = "TinyLlama/TinyLlama-1.1B-Chat-v1.0"
hf_pipe = pipeline("text-generation", model=model_name)
llm_pipeline = HuggingFacePipeline(pipeline=hf_pipe, model_kwargs={"temperature": 0.4, "max_length": 512})
```

I also used chat template from [here](https://huggingface.co/docs/transformers/main/en/chat_templating) first before passing them in `llm_pipeline`.

`hf_message = hf_pipe.tokenizer.apply_chat_template(message_template, tokenize=False, add_generation_prompt=True)`

`prompt = PromptTemplate.from_template(hf_message)`

Comment: I have since used `langchain==0.1.10` and it seems to work. now i am confused whether downgrading in the first place did anything.